# Reloading and Unloading CSS on Modal Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to unload css when the modal closes and reload css when the modal opens again. The reason for this is because I noticed that if the user stays on the page after closing the modal- the css remains and they'd have to refresh for the page to appear as it did before the modal was opened.

Another solution would be to change my CSS but as its hundreds of lines I would rather find a way to do this using javascript manipulation. Below is the code I was trying to use. Anyone know where I am going wrong? The modal opens with css but after closing the modal the modal does not reload the css when its opened again.

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    window.loadCSS(`pathname/css/mycssfile.css`);
});

$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("link[href*='mycssfile']").prop('disabled', true);
    $("link[href*='mycssfile']").remove();
});
```

Comment: There's something broken (why does a dialogue change the styling of the page? O.o), and you're now asking for a workaround instead of fixing the problem? Imho, that's a terrible idea.

Comment: @Andreas I have a modal form in my application and wanted to... style the form. Some of the styling is generic so the css file that gets loaded in affects some of the elements on the original webpage they use to access the form. I don't mind fixing it manually- thought it would be interesting to see a JS solution to this even though its not ideal

Answer (score 0):

You can make the style display or not. attache the CSS file to the `<head>` in the page you want it to open like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modal.css">
```

don't forget to make the modal display: none is the CSS file.

then make "open" link/ button like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('open1').style.display='block'"><i class="eye far fa-eye"></i></a>
```

in the modal don't forget to make the "close" link/button:

```
<span style="font-size: 40px;" onclick="document.getElementById('open1').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
```